# Web pages gets distorted when ever I try to specify a variable on my route

Tags: laravel

I tried parsing a variable through my route and but the CSS isn't rendered on the page and my page shows purely html=

Here is my web route;

```
Route::get('/create-transaction/{id}', 'AdminController@create')->name('Create Transaction');
```

And here is my controller;

```
public function create($id){
        $users = User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(100);
        return view('create-transaction')->with(compact('users', 'id'));

    }
```

I get this sam error with every other web page on my website when. once I parse in a variable through my route, the whole page losses it's formatting. I've tried the same page without parsing variables and it works fine but it's a different case when I parse in a variable

Here is my view page;

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
<section class="content-top-margin page-title-small border-bottom-light border-top-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="300ms">
                <!-- page title -->
                <h1 class="black-text">Create Transaction</h1>
                <!-- end page title -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 breadcrumb text-uppercase wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="600ms">
                <!-- breadcrumb -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/admin-dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/deposit" class="active">Withdrawals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/change-password">Change Password</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- end breadcrumb -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="wow fadeIn border-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-10 center-col">
                    @if (session('error'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            {{ session('error') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    @if (session('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('success') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <form action="/create-transaction" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Date</label>
                                <input type="text" name="current-password" class="form-control input-round big-input" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Amount</label>
                                <input type="text" name="current-password" class="form-control input-round big-input" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Type</label>
                                <input type="text" name="current-password" class="form-control input-round big-input" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Description</label>
                                <input type="text" name="current-password" class="form-control input-round big-input" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-black btn-small btn-round no-margin-bottom" type="submit">Create Transaction</button>
                        <!-- end button  -->
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
```

Comment: Please share your view file

Comment: You said it's an application-wide error so you may have to look into the `layouts.admin` view as well.

Comment: Everythings seems to be in order. the css doesn't just get rendered that's all